# Laravel Excel Error with SQ Server. Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint

Tags: laravel

I'm tryin to import and excel file to my SQL Server Database but when I try to create the form to upload the file I get this error:

Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint. (SQL: select top 1 * from [schedules] where [schedules].[id] = import)

[Screenshoot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MR4Aj.png)

Even when I have the function in the controller it throws this error. Seems that is trying to get 1 record from database but cannot pass the nvarchar to match the ID column.

I have checked the documentation and nothing. Made it a few times, different methods with same error.

***Seems that I figured it out. It was problem with the routing calling de show function***

Comment: Have you tried this [solution](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/167190/223248)?, you can use `->whereRaw()` to safely cast your nvarchar to bigint

Comment: The thing is that I have not made the query... it is done by Laravel Excel  and calls it directly when I try to create the form to upload the file.

Comment: It was a bad routing on web.php

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and trying to find the solution came upon this question.  Thankfully I read the comments as Fernando's solution was also mine.

This was caused by a misordered Route in web.php

```
Route::Get('label/{label}' ...
...
Route::Get('label/create' ...
```

I swapped the order and all fixed

```
Route::Get('label/create' ...
...
Route::Get('label/{label}' ...
```